# Help on apex Test Class.

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Following is my apex class....The lines not covered are => marked

```
 public class OrderTrackingClass{ 

public class Order {
    public Orders__c sob {get; set;}
    public OrderLine[] orderLines {get; set;} 
    public InvoiceLine[] invoiceLines {get; set;} 
    Order(Orders__c sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.orderLines = new OrderLine[] {};
        this.invoiceLines = new InvoiceLine[] {};
    }
}

public class OrderLine {
    public Order_Lines__c sob {get; set;}
    public ShipmentLine[] shipmentLines {get; set;}
    OrderLine(Order_Lines__c sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        this.shipmentLines = new ShipmentLine[] {};
    }
}

public class ShipmentLine {
 =>   public Shipment_Lines__c sob {get; set;}
 =>   ShipmentLine(Shipment_Lines__c sob) {
 =>       this.sob = sob;
    }
}

public class InvoiceLine{
  =>  public invoice_lines__c sob {get; set;}

  =>  InvoiceLine(invoice_lines__c sob) {
 =>    this.sob = sob;

    }
}
// Visualforce gets all data starting from here
 public Order[] orders {get; set;}

 public OrderTrackingClass() {
  init();
 }

 public void init() {

    orders = new Order[] {};

    Map<Id, Order> ordersMap = new Map<Id, Order>();
    for (Orders__c sob : [
            select id, name, number_of_line_items__c,Orders__c, customer_order_number__c, account__r.name,CreatedDate  
            from Orders__c
            where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')

            ]) {
        Order w = new Order(sob);
        ordersMap.put(sob.Id, w);
        orders.add(w);
    }

    Map<Id, OrderLine> orderLinesMap = new Map<Id, OrderLine>();
    for (Order_Lines__c sob : [
            select id,name, number_of_order_lines__c
            from Order_Lines__c
            where number_of_order_lines__c in :ordersMap.keySet()

            ]) 

            {
            system.debug('sob----->'+sob);
        OrderLine w = new OrderLine(sob);
        orderLinesMap.put(sob.Id, w);
        // Add child to correct parent
        ordersMap.get(sob.number_of_order_lines__c).orderLines.add(w);
        system.debug('sob2----->'+sob);
        system.debug('ordersMap----->'+ordersMap);
    }

    Map<Id, ShipmentLine> shipmentLinesMap = new Map<Id, ShipmentLine>();
    for (Shipment_Lines__c sob : [
            select id,name, order_lines__c
            from Shipment_Lines__c
            where order_lines__c in :orderLinesMap.keySet()

            ]) {
 =>         ShipmentLine w = new ShipmentLine(sob);
  =>      shipmentLinesMap.put(sob.Id, w);
        // Add child to correct parent

  =>        orderLinesMap.get(sob.order_lines__c).shipmentLines.add(w); 
    }

            Map<Id, InvoiceLine> invoiceLinesMap = new Map<Id, InvoiceLine>();
       for (invoice_Lines__c sob : [
            select invoices__r.invoice_no__c
            from invoice_Lines__c
            where orders__c in :ordersMap.keySet()

            ]) 

            {
            system.debug('sob----->'+sob);
  =>          InvoiceLine w = new InvoiceLine(sob);
  =>           InvoiceLinesMap.put(sob.Id, w);
        // Add child to correct parent
  =>           ordersMap.get(sob.orders__c).InvoiceLines.add(w);

      }
     }

    }
```

Following is my Test class

```
    @isTest
  public class OrderTrackingClass_TEST
    {  
          static testMethod void coverCode(){
          Test.startTest();

          OrderTrackingClass controller = new OrderTrackingClass(); 
          controller.init();                


          Account acc = new Account(Name='ABC Corp.');
          insert acc;

          orders__c tempOrder = new orders__c(name = '0001234567', account__c = acc.id );
          insert tempOrder;

          order_lines__c tempOL1 = new order_lines__c();

          tempOL1.Name = '10';
         // tempOL1.order_number__c= tempOrder.id;
          tempOL1.number_of_order_lines__c=tempOrder.id;
          tempOL1.status__c = 'Open';
          tempOL1.calculated_estimated_delivery_date__c = date.today();// fot invoiced
          tempOL1.planned_ship_date__c = date.today();
          insert tempOL1;

          shipment_lines__c tempSL = new shipment_lines__c();
          tempSL.order_lines__c = tempOrder.id;
          tempSL.Name = '100';  

          //tempSL.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';               
          tempSL.estimated_delivery_date__c = date.today(); 

           invoice_lines__c tempIL1 = new invoice_lines__c(name = '0001234567', orders__c = tempOrder.id);


          PageReference pageRef = Page.OrderTrackingClass;
          Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
          ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(tempOrder);
          ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',tempOrder.id);

          Test.stopTest();

    }
 }
```

Please guide me.  It seems I'm not covering the shipment and invoice lines . What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is not inserting the  `Shipment_lines__c` and `Invoice_lines__c` records. See the two insert lines below, which you are not doing in your code

```
shipment_lines__c tempSL = new shipment_lines__c();
...
insert tempSL; // This line is missing
...
invoice_lines__c tempIL1 = new invoice_lines__c(name = '0001234567', orders__c = tempOrder.id);
insert tempIL1; // This line is missing
```